# Sort by price is not working on magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, catalogsearch, price-sorting

This is a website link
https://magento-202257-609939.cloudwaysapps.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?product_list_dir=asc&q=wera

I am developing for my client and after a search of any product when we choose sort option by price its not working.

Can anyone give me solution for this?

Waiting!

Comment: check if you have any custom module that overrides sorting functionality in product listing

Comment: No custom module is installed.